# Не сохраняются сессии в Laravel 5

Tags: php, сессия, laravel

Проблема такая, что для каждого запроса создается новый файл сессии.
Получается, что по какой то причине меняется sessionid.
Работает одинаково для всех драйверов.
Права на storage 777.
На этом же сервере стоит laravel 4.0 - прекрасно работает.

В чем может быть косяк?

Comment: А что в конфигурации (config.php) прописано по поводу сессий?

Comment: Попробуй добавить:
'lifetime' => 120,' expire_on_close' => false,
В конфигурацию
У меня нет Laravel5 рядом, поэтому вот еще посмотри вариант:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24907858/session-not-working-in-laravel-4

Comment: Не помогло...  конфиг для сессий такой:                                        'driver' => env('SESSION_DRIVER', 'file'),
 'lifetime' => 10,
 'expire_on_close' => false,
 'encrypt' => false,
 'files' => storage_path().'/framework/sessions',
 'connection' => null,
 'table' => 'sessions',
 'lottery' => [2, 100],
 'cookie' => 'laravel_session',
 'path' => '/',
 'domain' => '',
 'secure' => true,  кстати, для memcached почему то тоже создаются файлы сессий

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема оказалась в настройках сессии, а именно в
'secure' => true
Поставил 'secure' => false - все заработало.
Кто-нибудь объяснит, как работают безопасные?

Answer (score 0):

Если `secure` равен `true`, то `cookie` с сессией будут отправлены браузером только через `HTTPS` соединение.

Иными словами, вы можете создать сессию, послать `cookie` пользователю, пользователь их получит и сохранит, но обратно этот `cookie` вы получите только по https соединению.

Вот и получается, что по http соединению браузер пользователя не посылает `cookie (laravel_session)`. И вы заново создаете сессию.

Answer (score 0):

Возможно кому то поможет. У меня была такая ситуация. Перепробовал все способы, которые нашел - не помогло. Включив в панели разработчика медленный инет заметил, что данные сначала все-таки приходят во view, а потом удаляются. Открыв локальный проект в другом браузере все работало. Методом тыка определил, что мешал мне Adblock